# Why is my layout change not reflecting in a Sinatra/Puma/Nginx production setup?

Tags: caching, nginx, sinatra, puma

I have a website running Sinatra and Puma with Nginx proxying traffic via an upstream to the Sinatra app.

Now I have made a change in one of the views. Because the Sinatra app is running in production mode, I have restarted both Puma and Nginx, but when refreshing the browser, I cannot see the change in the view.

The settings are all vanilla; I have not made any out-of-the ordinary settings, especially not relating to caching. I have also looked to see if there are any directories containing caches under /var for Nginx, but there are none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged this issue on the Sinatra GitHub site here: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1311

I eventually noticed that when I restarted Puma and checked the status, the process associated with the Puma socket always remained the same. So I killed that process and restarted Puma. Then, in the status, I noticed that the process now had a different number, and on refreshing the browser, the changes were reflecting.

I’m not sure if this is a temporary issue, but it did solve the issue for now.